# Docmd.OutputTo Excel - "Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected"

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am exporting some data to excel using a Docmd.Output.

`FileName = "CategoryBreakdown.xls"
 DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputStoredProcedure, sqlSP, acFormatXLS, FileName, True`

The error occurs when I've already exported the data once, and there is an open excel spreadsheet named "CategoryBreakdown.xls".

Is the best practice to use On Error and show a message telling the user to close the spreadsheet/save it under a different name? Or is there a way to check during runtime if there is a file open with that name and to provide a different file name before it crashes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As understood from you, you want to keep the previously exported excel files as well as the new exports.

so what you can do is to **create a public function** within a module, and an public increment variable, then **call that function** on a button click event and on the error 2302 as well...

> The public function

```
Option Compare Database
  Dim i As Integer
  Public Sub exportXLS()
    i = i + 1
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = "CategoryBreakdown" & i & ".xls"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "Table1", acFormatXLS, FileName, True
  End Sub
```

> The button click Function

```
Private Sub cmdExportXLS_Click()
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Call exportXLS
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  If Err.Number = 2302 Then
    Call exportXLS
  Else
    MsgBox "error msg when other error occurs:" & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
  End If
End Sub
```

This will increment the Filename on every export action or when and export action pops an error.

I hope this helps

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this. sans putting it in a public module so it could be reused. I like that idea.

Comment: in fact, i dont like using modules a lot, i prefer defining a class and put my functions in it, and for this case, i would put a shared key with methods needed to manipulate things. so its more secure and resuable

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
While Len(Dir(FileName)) <> 0
Dim i As Integer
i = i + 1
FileName = "CategoryBreakdown" & i & ".xls"
Wend
```

Critiques?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's best practice to add error handlers in your application to trap unexpected errors and share adequate information on what the user should do next.  Here's an example of error handler for your case:

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim FileName As String
    <...your other codes here...>

    FileName = "CategoryBreakdown.xls"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputStoredProcedure, sqlSP, acFormatXLS, FileName, True

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 2302 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot create " & FileName & " because it is currently open. Close the spreadsheet or save it under a different name.", vbExclamation, "Error"
    Else
        MsgBox "ExportToExcel encountered an unexpected error:" &  Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that looks nice.